# Redeeming minuteman savings stamps the old-fashioned way?

Tags: united-states, government-bonds

We just found in our house two books of 10¢ [Minuteman stamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_savings_stamps_of_the_United_States#Minuteman_Stamps), face value $2.90.  I see that they are sold as collectibles for a wide range of prices.

But I am **curious** whether there is still some government agency that will redeem them for original value.  I already know they're only worth ten cents that way, so please don't waste time telling me so.  Just curious.

In trying to find out, I only came across [sites selling them](https://www.mysticstamp.com/Products/United-States/S1/USA/) (besides the usual completely unrelated hits).

Comment: at first I thought you were asking how to redeem postal reply coupons, haha!

Comment: Basically it is redeemable. But it is unwise to do that unless it is under the bad condition that no collector one and abundances of it in the market. A booklet of stamps in whole normally fetch higher collection value compare individual one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a post by user *wt1* on stampcommunity.org from 2013 (in reply to another user who had picked-up a book of Minuteman and similar stamps at an outdoor antique market), they should still be redeemable at face-value:

> [...] as technically they still have "face value" upon application to:
>
> > US Bureau of the Public Debt
> >     200 Third Street
> >     Parkersburg, VA 26106-1328
>
> They can be redeemed for cash or used to the extent of their value in partial payment for a US Savings Bond.
>
> <sub>(Source: https://www.stampcommunity.org/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=32804#278640)</sub>

Although it also notes that they are probably (depending on condition) worth more philatelically.

As the [link you gave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_savings_stamps_of_the_United_States#Minuteman_Stamps) states, the intention was that these stamps would be used to buy *Series E War Bonds*, where a full book of 75 x 25-cent stamps (face-value $18.75) could buy one $25 Series E bond which would mature 10 years later.

The [Wikipedia page on the Series E bond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_E_bond#After_World_War_II) notes:

> After the war, Series E Bonds continued to be sold until June 1980 as part of the [United States Savings Bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Savings_Bonds) program, thereafter being replaced by Series EE bonds.

and the [Investopedia page](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/series-e-bond.asp) on the same subject also notes:

> The exchange of E Series bonds for H Series [was] allowed until 2004. That exchange is no longer offered. Instead, holders of mature Series E bonds can redeem them at financial institutions such as banks at an accrual value determined by the U.S. Treasury on a semi-annual basis. The final round of Series E Bonds stopped earning interest in 2010.

Comment: I was quite aware that their philatelic value is greater.  I assumed that as soon as I found them; it was confirmed by the prices request on the site I cited.